# How can I load the nsynth dataset on a normal local machine in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset

I've been attempting to load the NSynth dataset for use in tensorflow on my local machine. Google Collab is very powerful, but can't really be used to write full python applications to my knowledge.

However, when using the normal command

```py
ds = tfds.load('nsynth', split='train', shuffle_files=False, download=True,
                data_dir="data")
```

The data downloads fine, but the script ends silently unexpectedly, seemingly due to lack of disk space, despite there's over 250GB available before running the script, and the dataset isn't larger than this.

I'm not certain disk space is the issue, as the script fails silently after 30 minutes or so, and there is no verbose option for the load function.

How can I load it locally without freeing up more space?

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems downloading/extracting the files via tfds.load i strongly recommend to download them locally via:

https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/nsynth#files

Here you can choose the package you need and extract them locally yourself.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't include the GANSynth / other partitions which include other important information like f0 and f0_confidence. I'm using Collab for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on GCS, it returns only the first 1000 files per request if we want more than 1000 we have pass NextMarker (name of last file) and request again until we get all files. This way we can get all files without missing any.

This issue can be tracked at [#1938](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/1938).

As a workaround, you can try gsutil command to downlaod the data from GCS as shown below.

```
!gsutil cp -r "gs://tfds-data/datasets/nsynth/full/2.3.3" "/content/data"
```

Install gsutil locally: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install